# How could i detect breakpoints of a header with variable number of menus?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a header for a web application and i want this header to be configurable : admin can add or remove menus as he want.
For example :
[image]
Or
[image]

The breakpoint of these two navbar isn't the same.
So I'm wondering how could i deal with that ? How can I detect that the menus are too long for the screen so i have to reduce it ?

Media queries are fixed so it's not a good solution and I don't find how to do that in JavaScript.

Comment: Please, clarify your question. Do you want the menus don't overlap the logo of the header?

Comment: I just want to detect when will the menu overlap the logo if i resize the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic approach. It uses jQuery to detect the distance between the logo and the menu items, and if it goes below an arbitrary value (100px here), some css is added. You could expand this to do whatever you'd like when the distance gets too small. Lower the padding, logo size, swap in a mobile menu, etc.

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/schrdr/9hzye0aw/)

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  var menuOffset = $('.menu-items').offset().left
  var logoWidth = $('.logo').width();

  if (menuOffset - logoWidth <= 100) {
    $('.menu-items').css('background-color', 'red');
  } else if (menuOffset - logoWidth > 100) {
    $('.menu-items').css('background-color', 'blue');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.nav .menu-items {
  display: flex;
}
.nav .menu-items .item {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="nav">
  <div class="logo">
    logo
  </div>
  <div class="menu-items">
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
        <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```